# Given the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2e^{-(x+y)}$

Tags: probability-distributions

HW problem here. I want to check my first three answers, as well as get help on the last part.

Given the joint pdf 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2e^{-(x+y)}, \ \ \ \ 0\leq x \leq y, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y \geq 0$$

Find

(a) $P(Y<1|X<1)$

(b) $P(Y<1|X=1)$

(c) $f_{Y|x}(y)$

(d) $E(Y|x)$

For (a) I have:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{2e^{-(x + y)}dx}dy = .799$$

For (b):

$$\int_{0}^{1}{2e^{-(1 + y)}dy} = .465$$

For (c):

$$f_X(x) = -2(e^{-2y} - e^{-y})$$

Which gives:

$$f_{Y|x}(y) = -\frac{e^{-(x + y)}}{e^{-2y} - e^{-y}}$$

For (d), I'm not sure how to start it out. Can I get some hints? Also, did I slove a-c correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2e^{-(x+y)}, \quad 0\leq x \leq y, \; y \geq 0$

The thing to watch for is to ensure that $x\leq y$.

$\begin{align}\mathrm A)\quad
\mathsf P(Y<1\mid X<1) & = \frac{\mathsf P(Y<1, X<1)}{\mathsf P(X<1)}
\\[1ex] & =\dfrac{
\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_x^1 2e^{-(x+y)}\operatorname d y\operatorname d x 
}{
\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_x^\infty 2e^{-(x+y)}\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
}
\\[4ex]
\mathrm B)\quad
\mathsf P(Y<1\mid X=1)
& =\frac{
\displaystyle\int_1^1 2 e^{-(1+y)}\operatorname d y
}{
\displaystyle\int_1^\infty 2 e^{-(1+y)}\operatorname d y
}
\\[1ex] & = 0
\\[4ex]
\mathrm C)\quad
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) & = \frac{
f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{
2 e^{-(x+y)}
}{
\displaystyle\int_0^x 2e^{-(s+y)}\operatorname d s}\operatorname {\bf 1}_{0\leq x\leq y\lt \infty
}
\\[4ex]
\mathrm D)\quad
\mathsf E(Y\mid X=x) & = \frac{
\displaystyle\int_x^\infty 2te^{-(x+t)}\operatorname d t
}{
\displaystyle\int_0^\infty 2 e^{-(x+t)}\operatorname d t
}
\end{align}$

Comment: Did you write that backwards? You have y depending on x, not x depending on y.

Comment: @David $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_x^1 f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x = \int_0^1\int_0^y f(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y \\ \displaystyle\int_0^1\int_x^\infty f(x,y) \operatorname d y\operatorname d x = \int_0^1 \int_0^y f(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y+\int_1^\infty\int_0^1 f(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y$